# How do I use third party scripting additions in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

So I have installed some third party Applescript additions which are located in `/Library/ScriptingAdditions/` and have the `.osax` file extension.

All of them contain scripting definitions which describe some functions I would like to take advantage of.

Since the directory is called `ScriptingAdditions` I tried to just `use scripting additions`, with no success however.

**Note:** There is a chance that those "scripting additions" are part of a third party Applescript-editor called [smile by Satimage](https://satimage.fr/software/en/smile/index.html). If there is a chance to use those additions in vanilla Applescript too, that would be great.

Comment: @matt The newest beta version sort of runs, but it is a pain to do practically anything in it so I would like to have the additions of smile in Applescript.

Comment: JMO I'd stay away from Satimage as it cause all sort of issues with existing _code_ prior to installing. That said, this was probably 10 years ago so I'm foggy on any details.

Comment: @matt I know, but can you add them to your vanilla scripts?

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, I just downloaded it once and then immediately deleted it again after I noticed that I didn't like the editor. The things were installed so they kept being installed.

Comment: Third party `Scripting Additions` no longer work in AppleScripts.  https://latenightsw.com/mojave-brings-in-big-security-changes/

Comment: Since Mojave you don’t, since they are no longer loaded.  The only work-around is that you are still able to load a scripting addition if it is in an applet’s bundle and code-signed with the same identity.

Comment: @wch1zpink Thanks for letting me know that. I should have done more research.

Comment: @red_menace Thanks a lot, if it's to complicated I will probably just rely on Applescript stdlib.